# Using .Net OnSerializingAttribute to alter variable names?

Tags: .net, serialization, .net-2.0, obfuscation

in order to obfuscate application code but still be able to use serialization to save application data, I want to map the names of all serialized members to custom serialization names. I know that I can achieve this by implementing the ISerizableInterface, but in the MSDN they suggest the use of OnDeserializedAttribute, OnSerializingAttribute, OnSerializedAttribute, and OnDeserializingAttribute for serialization. So I would like to use the OnSerializingAttribute to rename my members. The problem is that I can't find a way to explicitly determine the names under which a member is serialized.

Is it possible to explicitly define the names for serialization using the OnSerializingAttribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think custom serialization and ISerializable interface will be the most efficient way in your case. Check out the sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(VS.71).aspx). Also [here's](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxremoting/thread/22273542-504c-4510-9173-216c889f0540/#) a good discussion thread towards both ISerializable and serialization attributes you've mentioned.

I would say that if you want to have a full control over the format you should use custom serializer and if you want responding the (de)serialization flow the attributes is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

(**edit**: I decided to write this up as a [blog entry](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html), as I've seen it be useful a number of times)

I've had users before use [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) for this; this uses Google's dense binary "protocol buffers" wire format, which doesn't include any names on the wire - just numbers. This means that:

- the names are not exposed on the wire
- it doesn't matter whether the name in the class at runtime is "DateOfBirth" or "a1v"

This works by assigning an integer tag to members (properties or fields) - for example:

```
[ProtoMember(4)]
public DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}
```

Only the "4" is used in the serialization, but (importantly) you don't need to maintain lots of serialization code. Can also be hooked into `ISerializable` very easily if you need to use remoting, and also has a WCF hook if you want.

Disclosure: I'm the author, so I'm biased - but the tool is free, so you don't lose anything by having a look ;-p

Comment: Sounds that protobuf-net is the right tool for the job, I will give it a try. Although it will obviously break compatibility with existing serialization data files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET4 or .NET4.5 you can define your own DataContractResolver to rename the attributes, but it would be simpler to just use compacted named in the `[DataMember(...)]` attribute